What is the best way to define a constant with a WebComponent?
Update: I added more details of how I'm using the constants in response to questions.  The actual problem I'm observing is that the constants are added to the global object, and so I'm worried about potential name collisions.
I defined a WebComponent for my team.  The component uses several constants, which - for convenience - I just defined at the top of the file.
const SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE = "session-keep-alive";
const MILLISECONDS_IN_MINUTE = 60000;

const PAGE_TIMEOUT_DIALOG_ID = `${SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE}-extend-session-dialog`;
const YES_BUTTON_ID = `${PAGE_TIMEOUT_DIALOG_ID}-yes-button`;
const NO_BUTTON_ID = `${PAGE_TIMEOUT_DIALOG_ID}-no-button`;

// TEMPLATES
const PAGE_TIMEOUT_DIALOG_TEMPLATE = document.createElement("template");
PAGE_TIMEOUT_DIALOG_TEMPLATE.innerHTML = `
    <uef-dialog action-required="" backdrop="" width="500px" id="${PAGE_TIMEOUT_DIALOG_ID}">
        <uef-typography slot="uef-dialog-header">Warning</uef-typography>
        <uef-typography line-height="1.5" slot="uef-dialog-body">
            Your session will expire in 5 minutes. Do you want to extend it?
        </uef-typography>
        <uef-button-group slot="uef-dialog-footer" alignment="right" direction="rtl">
            <uef-button fill="solid" id="${YES_BUTTON_ID}">Yes</uef-button>
            <uef-button fill="outline" id="${NO_BUTTON_ID}">No</uef-button>
        </uef-button-group>
    </uef-dialog>`;

class SessionKeepAlive extends HTMLElement {

    connectedCallback() {
        document.body.appendChild(PAGE_TIMEOUT_DIALOG_TEMPLATE.content);
 
        this.dialog = document.getElementById(PAGE_TIMEOUT_DIALOG_ID);

        let yesButton = this.dialog.querySelector(`#${YES_BUTTON_ID}`);
        yesButton.addEventListener("buttonClick", this.yesButtonClickHandler.bind(this));

        let noButton = this.dialog.querySelector(`#${NO_BUTTON_ID}`);
        noButton.addEventListener("buttonClick", this.noButtonClickHandler.bind(this));
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
        if (name === "delay") {
            if (!isNaN(newValue)) {
                this.timeoutDelay = newValue * MILLISECONDS_IN_MINUTE;
            }
        }
    }

    yesButtonClickHandler() {
        this.dialog.removeAttribute("open");
        ... // Code to extend session elided
    }

    noButtonClickHandler() {
        this.dialog.removeAttribute("open");
    }
}

window.customElements.define(SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE, SessionKeepAlive);

In this simplified example, you can see how I use two constants.  One I use to register the WebComponent and also define IDs for elements in the component.  This constant seems to genuinely be greater than the scope of the WebComponent.
The other - MILLISECONDS_IN_MINUTES - could probably just be replaced by a literal.  I did consider defining it as just another property in the constructor, but I wanted to know the best way to handle these situations.
I tried a few things - including using an anonymous function to limit the scope:
(function() {
    // The above code, here
}) ();

This worked, but it feels wrong.
I tried using the "static" keyword to define these as class-level variables.  Unfortunately, that's not how the "static" keyword works in JavaScript.
I also considered using a Constants file, but the point of using components is to encapsulate code, not to put aspects in separate files.
Any advice?

MILLISECONDS_IN_MINUTE is a genuine constant - it should not be defined in the constructor, the number of ms in a minute will never change. The other one seems like it could potentially be a default value and be configurable at the scope of each component instance. Forget about limiting the scope for a second - what's the actual problem you are observing? It seems like it might lie in this sentence: and also define IDs for elements in the component. Also This worked, but it feels wrong. - it's not remotely clear what you mean when you say "worked"

What difference could it possibly make? You aren't exporting them. Why would you make them a static if you aren't planning for consumers of the class to use them?

Do uou mean a unique ID? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID

It feels like you should put your actual content into the shadowRoot instead, triggering your dialog from there? Otherwise you should consider making dialogs on the fly and calling a method? The advantage of the shadowRoot is that they have their own scope for id once more, so you can "repeat" the element with the same ids in the shadow and they won't affect each other. That's true encapsulation.

I tried to use the Shadow Root, but I still had to define a template to copy in.  I agree that would avoid the ID collisions I'm concerned with.  Unfortunately, we're using a web component library (UEF) that is brought in through the CDN.  When I put the UEF elements in the shadow root, they don't style correctly. To me, React does a much better job with rendering and encapsulation.  I'm not sure why the markup wasn't better integrated into the Web Component specification.

The shadow root isolates its inner elements from styles outside. If you don't want this, you can just append the elements directly to your custom elements with this.appendChild(...).
Also you probably meant to do PAGE_TIMEOUT_DIALOG_TEMPLATE.content.cloneNode(true). Without cloneNode, you're actually moving the contents out of the template rather than copying them.

If you're worried about name collisions, ask about name collisions. Currently the question is too broadly scoped and asking for opinions.

If you want limit the scope (without using modules), you can just use a block, like this:
{
    const MY_CLASS_NAME = "my-class";
    class MyClass extends HTMLElement {}
}


I like this idea - we'll try it

For now I've decided to recommend using the anonymous function closures:
(function() {

    const MY_CLASS_NAME = "my-class";

    class MyClass extends HTMLElement {
        // Stuff
    }

    window.customElements.define(MY_CLASS_NAME, MyClass);
}) ()

This works, and it's a common practice in JavaScript.
